# Can't set up libvirt-go properly

Tags: go, libvirt

I use Debian 10. My libvirt version is  5.0.0. libvirt-dev is already the newest version (5.0.0-4+deb10u1). When I add "github.com/libvirt/libvirt-go" to my project it says, for instance `Connect not declared by package libvirt`. What could it be? thanks

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys, it was CGO_ENABLED="0" but should be CGO_ENABLED="1"